# Add-ons on GRASS (win7)

Tags: grass-gis, windows-7, add-ons

Can someone help me to install an add-on for GRASS 6.4.3RC3, on Windows 7? I tried several approaches, but wasn't able to install the add-on. I found several topics here and on the web but the approach doesn't work.

Using `g.extension`, I install `r.basin` and it seems that everything is OK, but when I try to use `r.basin` it doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you provide us some more information - like any error messages etc.? Between there is a similar question which might help you - [How to install add-ons in GRASS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/how-to-install-add-ons-in-grass?rq=1)

Comment: I tried to install r.basin via g.extension on my Windows7 machine, but although it said "Successfully installed", I'm not able to see the module and start it!

Comment: If you have not done this already, I would suggest you read this tutorial for [r.basin](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.basin). You may have to convert your data to projected coordinates for the module to work.

Answer (score 3):

Please enter "r.basin" (without the quotes) in the Command Console tab to see if it is there. In GRASS GIS 7 the addons should be automatically registered in the menu (maybe not the case in GRASS 6).

According to http://grass.osgeo.org/download/addons/ the binaries for r.basin are correctly generated and available.

Comment: oK, I will try. Maybe I can try also to istall grass 7. But I'm wondering if the problem could be the windows machine.

Comment: If I try to do g.extension from command console it appears that I need subversion...

Comment: .. then something went wrong. On Windows, simply precompiled binaries should be downloaded (subversion is used in case of Unix-like operating systems). The latest winGRASS7 contains also proxy support for the extension manager.

Comment: I noticed that, for grass 6.4.3RC3, the problem appear with phyton scripts addons (like r.basin). While with addon as r.viewshed it's easy to import it from http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/addons/. Any suggestion??

Comment: Perhaps contact the author... I have no idea and the file structure looks the same. In any case, since it is a script, it is sufficient to copy it, no compilation needed.

Comment: Ok thanks, but it's normal to see on command console r.basin.py? shouldn't be r.basin only?

Comment: this is the error: